# jQuery - Get input attribute and add it after the input as a text

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="list">
    <input checked="checked" data-blacklist="[392,340,393]" data-parentarticleid="249" data-price="0" data-price-included="1" data-string-value="2x500GB SATA2" id="article_249" name="hardwareSetHD" type="radio" value="249"><label for="article_249">2x500GB SATA2 <span></span> </label>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <input checked="checked" data-blacklist="[392,340,393]" data-parentarticleid="249" data-price="10" data-price-included="1" data-string-value="4x500GB SATA2" id="article_241" name="hardwareSetHD" type="radio" value="241"><label for="article_241">2x500GB SATA2 <span></span> </label>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <input checked="checked" data-blacklist="[392,340,393]" data-parentarticleid="242" data-price="20" data-price-included="1" data-string-value="8x500GB SATA2" id="article_242" name="hardwareSetHD" type="radio" value="242"><label for="article_242">8x500GB SATA2 <span></span> </label>
</div>
```

**What i want?**

When the document is loaded to ADD in `<span></span>` after the input radio, the text holded in `data-price`.

Here is what i tried:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=hardwareSetRAM]').this(text($(this).attr( "data-price" )));
});
</script>
```

So how can i get the `data-price` from every input with name `hardwareSetHD` and add it as a text after the input ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one input with the same name, otherwise when you post the form it will be messed up

Comment: Well you can... It's not illegal. It will just produce unexpected results. Perhaps that is what the OP wants...

Comment: With a radio button, you typically want exactly that, the same name...

Comment: Oh, yeah @Chris is right, my bad

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over each row, grab the value of price and update the span tag.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.list').each(function() {

        var inp = $(this).find('input[type=radio]'),
            span = $(this).find('span');

        var price = inp.data('price');

        span.text( price );

    });

});
```

[`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)